# What is the value of angle x in the figure, if: AP = 3BQ.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:
[image]

My progresss:

$T.Tales: \frac{CB}{AC}=\frac{CQ}{CP}\\
\triangle CPA\sim\triangle CQB: \frac{AP}{BQ} = \frac{AC}{BC} = \frac{PC}{CQ} = 3\\
\triangle FKE \sim \triangle EBC: \\
\frac{KE}{KF}=\frac{BC}{BE}\implies 
\frac{AB}{AF-AK}=\frac{BC}{BE}\rightarrow \frac{AB}{{AF-BE}}=\frac{BC}{BE}\\
\frac{BE}{AF-BE}=\frac{BC}{AB} =\frac{1}{2}\implies AF = 3BE$

I think the solution will be through a notable triangle (1: 2). I would need to show that $BE = 2CE$ or $BC = 2BQ$

[image]

Comment: Hint: Show that $CE:CF = 1:3$, find $EB:FA$ and $EB:EC$.

Comment: @CalvinLin..I find $\triangle EBC \sim \triangle FAC \implies \frac{CE}{CF}=\frac{BQ}{AP}=\frac{BQ}{3BQ} \therefore \frac{CE}{CF} = \frac{1}{3}\\ \triangle EBC \implies \triangle CBQ\implies  \frac{EB}{BC}=\frac{BQ}{QC}$

Comment: @ACB...grateful ..I already realized where I went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your diagram, show $ \small AF = 3BE = 3 r$ (If $r$ is the radius of the smaller circle)
Then $ \small FE = AF + BE = 4 BE = 4r$
$ \small FK = AF - AK = AF - BE = 2 r$
$ \small FK:FE = 1:2$. So $ \small x = \angle FEK = ?$

Comment: grateful ..I already realized where I went wrong

Comment: Your diagram was spot on so you should have easily got the answer if you did not make a mistake. When I was a student, I usually took a break and came back to the same problem later and that helped many a times in spotting my mistake or getting a new idea to solve the problem. What worked for me may not work for everyone and vice versa :)

Comment: You're right, but what happens to me is that sometimes I focus on a certain figure and let others go unnoticed...

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$-radius of big circle, $r$-radius of small circle. From similar triangles, $R=3r$.

Also it is easy to prove $2CE=EF$, therefore $CE=\frac{R+r}2=2r$.

As $BE=r$, from $\triangle BEC$ $\implies\sin x=\frac12\:\therefore x=30^\circ$.